# create a function in header.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function

i created a wordpress website theme and i  want to create a function in the header.php that function should create a menu of one link that can be changed by using any way like for example widget

this is the link :

```
    <li><a href="#">arabic</a></li>
```

and i want the function to let me change the url to go to page 
like when i am in "**contact-en**" page the url of the link should be "**contact-ar**"
and when i am i page "**contact-ar**" the link should be "**contact-en**"

Comment: Simplest way is create two different menu for your languages. And called the menu according to language selected.

Comment: can you please tell me how i could do that

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use Menu for WordPress?

To use this, go to "Appearance" -> "Menus".

Make a menu with any name. Select the menu from "Main Menu" and save it.

Put your link under "Custom Links" and the text you want to show under "Label" and click on Add to menu. Repeat this process until all are put. Then save it and the menu will appear now in your header menu.

Ask me if you have any further questions regarding this topic.